# How to unlearn missdetection object on tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I train SSD model on tensorflow to detect bowler hat. My TfRecord is compose of images which contains people with bowler hat and my validation dataset contains bowler hat and people with no bowler hat . 
After 10000 iterations, peoples wearing bowler hat is well detected but some people with no bowler hat is also detected. The top of their head are detected.

How to unlearn people with not bowler hat? Because in my train dataset, all people wearing bowler hat. Should I had a label "people with no bowler hat" to increase my train dataset ?

Here is the pipeline.conf I use :

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
          anchorwise_output: true
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          anchorwise_output: true
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 24
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00400000018999
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.949999988079
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
      decay: 0.899999976158
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 200000
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/data/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/data/data/default.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 2000
  max_evals: 500
  use_moving_averages: false
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics" 
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/data/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/data/data/default.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should have people without bowler hats in your training data, else the network won't be able to learn any of the distinctive features of the hat. Instead, the network will learn to just always indiscriminately classify the input data as having a bowler hat (which is effectively a global minima for the training set).

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. The question is should I had in my dataset images containing one the same image people with hat and people with not hat. Or should I had an other object detection, like people with not hat? In that case what should I labelize (top of head only)?